# Multi-processing a shell script within python

Tags: python, multithreading, shell

My Requirement is to run a shell function or script in parallel with multi-processing. Currently I get it done with the below script that doesn't use multi-processing. Also when I start 10 jobs in parallel, one job might get completed early and has to wait for the other 9 jobs to complete. I wanted eliminate this with the help of multiprocessing in python.

```
i=1 
total=`cat details.txt  |wc -l`
while [ $i -le $total ]
do
name=`cat details.txt | head -$i | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}'
age=`cat details.txt | head -$i | tail -1 | awk '{print $2}'
./new.sh $name $age  &
   if (( $i % 10 == 0 )); then wait; fi
done
wait
```

I want to run `./new.sh $name $age` inside a python script with multiprocessing enabled(taking into account the number of cpu) As you can see the value of $name and $age would change in each execution. Kindly share your thoughts

Comment: Your code is already using multiprocessing: Each invocation of `./new.sh` is run in a separate process and will be scheduled by the OS.

Comment: @MichaelJaros. Ok, But My requirement is also to start the 11 the job when one of the first 10 jobs end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, your whole schell script could be replaced with:

```
awk '{ print $1; print $2; }' details.txt | xargs -d'\n' -n 2 -P 10 ./new.sh
```

A simple python solution would be:

```
from subprocess import check_call
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool

def call_script(args):
    name, age = args  # unpack arguments
    check_call(["./new.sh", name, age])

def main():
    with open('details.txt') as inputfile:
        args = [line.split()[:2] for line in inputfile]
    pool = Pool(10)
    # pool = Pool()  would use the number of available processors instead
    pool.map(call_script, args)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Note that this uses `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool` (a thread pool) to call the external script, which in this case is preferable to a process pool, since all the `call_script` method does is invoke the script and wait for its return. Doing that in a worker process instead of a worker thread wouldn't increase performance since this is an IO based operation. It would only increase the overhead for process creation and interprocess communication.

Comment: .the shell script you suggested worked and I wanted to try out the python code too. I am getting this error       " AttributeError: 'ThreadPool' object has no attribute 'starmap'"    My python version is 2.6

Comment: You're right, `starmap` was introduced in python3.3 - changed the example to use `map` instead

Comment: Thanks a lot @mata. As you said the shell script you shared is better in performance.