# running N process in parallel in linux

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to create python script that will read commands from a file then run N of them simultaneously. This is what I have so far which does run N in parallel.

```
from subprocess import Popen
import time
with open('commands.txt') as f:
    commands = f.read().split('\n')
test_number = 20
while True:
    processes = [];time.sleep(6)
    for com in commands[test_number -20:test_number]:
        processes.append(Popen(com, shell=True))
        time.sleep(6)

    for i, process in enumerate(processes):
         process.wait()
         print(f"Command #{i} finished")
    test_number += 20
```

I need to put 6 seconds delay between each command, in my solution the fastest command will have to wait for the slowest one before running another command in the `while(true)`. Is there a better way to do this?

- I prefer a python solution but also ok with C

Comment: Is the issue that it works but it's too slow?

Comment: `time.sleep(6)` probably isn't helping

Comment: You likely don't have 20 virtual cores on your machine, so are actually slowing things down. Use the multiprocessing module.

Comment: Run the commands once in sequence to get a baseline for how long it could take.

Comment: @MadPhysicist the commands are fed from a sql database which takes around 2 seconds to communicate such that p1 starts and prepare the new data for p2 and so on.  if I run them like `p1&p2&p3&p4....` they will all be fed the same info which is something I do not want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `multiprocess.Pool` to create a pool of subprocesses and run your shell scripts inside them, like it's described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29714832/multi-processing-a-shell-script-within-python).

```
import time
from subprocess import Popen
from multiprocessing import Pool

with open('commands.txt') as f:
    commands = f.read().split('\n')

def run_com(com, i):
    Popen(com, shell=True)
    # time.sleep(10)  # here only for testing
    print(f"Command #{i} finished")

test_number = 20
pool = Pool(test_number)
for i, com in enumerate(commands):
    time.sleep(6)  # wait 6 seconds between starting each command
    pool.apply_async(run_com, (com, i))  # run command in pool
pool.close()  # once tasks are completed the worker processes exit
pool.join()  # waits for all the tasks to finish
```

This way the pool will keep track of which of its worker processes are occupied and will assign a task to one if it's free, so your processes that take longer will not halt others.

Comment: will this cause starvation on the fast commands, or at all point it will have `test_number` running?

Comment: after the first `test_number` number of processes are started, all the `test_number` subprocesses will be occupied until all tasks are finished. fast tasks will occupy a subprocess for a shorter amount of time. so, yeah it will not cause any starvation

Comment: This answer does not limit the Number, I ran it and it kept going way beyond the 20 limit

Comment: yes because previous processes have finished. do `time.sleep(1000)` inside the `run_com()` to see if you'll have more than 20 processes running at the same time. I tested it.